# python profile names for multiple instances of same program

Tags: python, profiling, profile

I have multiple instances of same program running ,my situation demands that I should kill a specific instance of a program in case three instances are running I should  kill one of them. How should I achieve this? Is it possible to create profile names for each instance and kill one  by using that? If so How? or is there any other way I did lots of reading about this but could not.

Comment: What method do you prefer for killing?

Comment: By using profile  names but  I  dont know and unable to find  how to create profile name for a script for multiple instances , as of now  I have only one instance of program so I am killing it by getting the process Id.

Comment: It might be easier to not let a fourth instance start, than to figure out how to randomly kill one that is already running. What have you tried?

Comment: But my situation demands that I have to kill a specific instance .